# Integration of a rotated triangle: determining the slope of a side

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I'm working through MIT's OCW single-variable calculus course. The problem is taken from Problem set 7: Question 4B-5.[1](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-3-the-definite-integral-and-its-applications/part-b-second-fundamental-theorem-areas-volumes/problem-set-7/)

Q: Find the volume of an equilateral triangle with side length *a* which is rotated around one of its sides.

I am actually doing the calculus side okay, I believe. My difficulty is with the trigonometry/geometry setting up the problem. Here is how I set up the integral:

$$
2 \int_0^\frac{a}{2} \pi(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{a}x)^2dx
$$

My integrand is apparently wrong. I've calculated $y$ to be a function of $x$ such that $y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{a}x$. The solution sets it up the integral exactly the same, except that $y = \sqrt{3}x$.

**Here is how I derived the integrand:**

Let the equilateral triangle sit with one side along the x-axis and its leftmost vertex at (0,0) and its rightmost vertex at (a, 0). The strategy will be to split the triangle in half, integrate the rotated solid around the x-axis, and multiply by two to get the whole triangle.

So the function to be integrated is a simple linear *f(x)* from 0 to $\frac{a}{2}$. Great. But what *is* $f(x)$? Here's where I go wrong.

I derived the slope of the line of *f(x)* by observing that the vertex at (0,0) is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ radians. Using sohcahtoa, I calculated the **height of the triangle** (i.e., $f(\frac{a}{2})$) as:$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$$

To then derive the slope of *f*, I simply did rise-over-run, i.e. (plugging in for $\sin\frac{\pi}{3})$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\div\frac{a}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{a}$$

Which is the slope of the function *f(x)*. I will leave it here, as I don't think the calculus is the problem. Clearly, I've done something wrong in the way I derived the slope of $f(x)$. What am I missing? What would have been the correct way to calculate $f(x)$ to arrive at $y = \sqrt{3}x$?

Comment: Minor slip, the height is $a\sin(\pi/3)$. Of course the slope does not depend on $a$. Side comment: As a matter of reflex, I would take the triangle to be of side say $1$ and multiply by $a^3$ at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but height needs to be $a\sin\left(\frac \pi 3\right)$. Then slope is given by $\dfrac {\frac {a\sqrt 3}2}{\frac a2} = \sqrt 3$.

Comment: Aha - in other words, the a coefficient is in all the sohcahtoa equations, but with the unit circle it's "invisible" because it is always equal to 1? I ask because I was unaware of such a rule (though it makes sense) and I want to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here, our "unit circle" is the $\frac a2$-circle (radius $\frac a2)$ !

Comment: Don't you mean the a-circle?

Comment: Yes, of course! Silly me!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV +1

Comment: Thanks, @Amzoti! I hope work is calming down a bit for you!